# I am employed and can bear all my expenses, but can my brother sponsor me at the same time?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

Should I mention about my brother sponsoring me for UK? Can I have another person bearing my expenses other than me?

Comment: Is your brother actually going to pay for some of the trip?

Comment: Yes, he will be paying for me and my mother. My mother depends on him. On the other hand I also work in his company. (Family business)

Comment: Is it ok if i write in the covering letter that me and my brother will share the expenses equally?

Comment: @Fam No, if your brother is financing some or all of the costs of your trip you must state that in your application and provide evidence that he is willing and able to meet that commitment. It’s not sufficient just to include a reference to who is paying in a covering letter.

Answer (score 3):

The Immigration Rules V4.2(e) states “The applicant must have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to their visit without working or accessing public funds. This includes the cost of the return or onward journey, any costs relating to dependants, and the cost of planned activities such as private medical treatment.”

Although V4.3 says that a 3rd party can provide funds, maintenance and accommodation, an applicant has a much stronger case if they can show they meet 4.2(e) in their own right. If you don’t need a sponsor, don’t mention one.

If someone is paying some or all of your trip expenses you must state that information in the application and provide evidence that the person is willing and able to fulfil the commitment, for example a letter from the 3rd party, their bank statements and payslips.

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules